# Error when I try to pass a POST or GET variable with the value of "Search Engine Optimization"

Tags: forms, apache, post, get, cpanel

This is extremely strange, at first I thought it was an issue with FormMail but upon further inspection I realized that I can not pass any POST or GET variable with the value of "Search Engine Optimization".  If I change it to say "SEO" it works fine.  Has anyone ever seen this? Is it something server side?  How can I change it?

Server stats:
cPanel Version  11.44.0 (build 29)
Apache version  2.2.27
PHP version     5.3.28

The error is:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1

Sorry if this has been answered before but as you can imagine any search with the words "search engine optimization" come up with a zillion results.

Comment: Are you sure it's just "Search Engine Optimization" and not any term with a space?

Comment: Yeah, positive, there are a handful of other options with spaces.

Comment: This sounds very much like a spam filtering issue. What happens if you have a variable containing drug names or other spammy terms?  Do you have any kind of spam filter installed to your knowledge?